# Overriding WPF DragMove() to snap to grid?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WFP app which displays a series of borderless windows upon the desktop. They can be arranged as the user requires, and I should like to have them snap to an invisible grid, to aid with perfect alignment. I can achieve this with code along the following lines, handling the LocationChanged event and forcing my window position to move incrementally:

```
    private void Window_LocationChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int xProximity = (int)this.Left % 50;
        if (xProximity <= 10 || xProximity >= 40)
            this.Left = ((int)Math.Round(this.Left / 50.0)) * 50;

        int yProximity = (int)this.Top % 50;
        if (yProximity <= 10 || yProximity >= 40)
            this.Top = ((int)Math.Round(this.Top / 50.0)) * 50;
    }
```

This approach however is only reactionary, in that the window can be seen to redraw in the location the mouse really takes it, then snaps back instantly. To get the smooth effect I'm after, I think I need to override DragMove so that the window doesn't get taken with the mouse in the first place. Proactive rather than reactive, if you will - I hope this makes sense - I've seen a few threads hit upon the same problem but nothing with an answer! Thank you all :)